# Serialize complex form to JSON object using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, forms, serialization

I've been searching for hours for this and haven't found an answer.
Please read through the whole question before flaming! :)

I have a form similar to this:

```
<form id="sample">
 <input name="name" type="text" value="name value" />

 <input name="phone[0][type]" type="text" value="cell" />
 <input name="phone[0][number]" type="text" value="000" />

 <input name="phone[1][type]" type="text" value="home" />
 <input name="phone[1][number]" type="text" value="111" />
</form>
```

And need to be able to serialize it to this:

```
{
 name: 'name value',

 phone: [
  {
   type: 'cell',
   number: '000'
  },
  {
   type: 'home',
   number: '111'
  }
 ]
}
```

I have tried most answers on SO including jquery-json libraries and most of them return something like this:

```
{
 'name': 'name value',
 'phone[0][type]': 'cell',
 'phone[0][number]': '000',
 'phone[1][type]': 'home',
 'phone[1][number]': '111',
}
```

This is something **I cannot use**! :P

Thanks everyone in advance.

Comment: Please look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69222405/4632019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [form serialize javascript (no framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11661187/form-serialize-javascript-no-framework)

Comment: possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70057955/2377343

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this code I wrote for you... Works fine for me, just using your data result. You can work on it and make a simple jQuery plugin...

The sample need JSON.stringify to work fully.

```
var d = {
    'name': 'name value',
    'phone[0][type]': 'cell',
    'phone[0][number]': '000',
    'phone[1][type]': 'home',
    'phone[1][number]': '111',
};

$(document).ready(function(){

    arrangeJson(d);
    alert(JSON.stringify(d));
});

function arrangeJson(data){
    var initMatch = /^([a-z0-9]+?)\[/i;
    var first = /^\[[a-z0-9]+?\]/i;
    var isNumber = /^[0-9]$/;
    var bracers = /[\[\]]/g;
    var splitter = /\]\[|\[|\]/g;

    for(var key in data) {
        if(initMatch.test(key)){
            data[key.replace(initMatch,'[$1][')] = data[key];
        }
        else{
            data[key.replace(/^(.+)$/,'[$1]')] = data[key];
        }
        delete data[key];
    }


    for (var key in data) {
        processExpression(data, key, data[key]);
        delete data[key];
    }

    function processExpression(dataNode, key, value){
        var e = key.split(splitter);
        if(e){
            var e2 =[];
            for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
                    if(e[i]!==''){e2.push(e[i]);} 
            }
            e = e2;
            if(e.length > 1){
                var x = e[0];
                var target = dataNode[x];
                if(!target){
                    if(isNumber.test(e[1])){
                        dataNode[x] = [];
                    }
                    else{
                        dataNode[x] ={}
                    }
                }
                processExpression(dataNode[x], key.replace(first,''), value);
            }
            else if(e.length == 1){
                dataNode[e[0]] = value;
            }
            else{
                alert('This should not happen...');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like magic. Had a little modification to it to handle a situation where your List is in the form 

var d = {
    'name': 'name value',
    'phone[0].type': 'cell',
    'phone[0].number': '000',
    'phone[1].type': 'home',
    'phone[1].number': '111',
};

The result has (.) in from of the inner list Key, So I added <e2[0] = e2[0].replace('.','');> after the first for loop in the processExpression() function.

Comment: _key_ is twice declared in the function.

Answer (score 6):

There is also the following library

http://code.google.com/p/form2js/

Answer (score 2):

This worked very well for me. This doesn't need to have the form2js library.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function serializeObject() {
        var o = {};
        var a = this.serializeArray();
        $.each(a, function () {
            if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
                if (!o[this.name].push) {
                    o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                }
                o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
            } else {
                o[this.name] = this.value || '';
            }
        });
        return o;
    };
```

To serialise the form data I used this code then.

```
JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject());//'this' points to the form
```

If you have any doubts please feel free to add comment.

Comment: What does your form look like in order for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

With this structure, I don't think any JSON library can do all the work.
So, I think that is more easy to write our own conversion loop.

**Here is the code to your serialization: http://jsfiddle.net/7MAUv/1/**

The logic is pretty simple, the secret is the `eval` to run Strings like dynamic commands.
I tried to make it as easier as possible, almost all lines are commented.

BTW, feels free to make questions.

Comment: Your code works perfectly Erick.
Thank you very much for posting it.

I will try and see if can be done without the eval part but should be awesome for now.

Answer (score 0):

Its not exactly what you asked for, but if you are using jQuery library and need your complex form serialized for a purpose of sending it in ajax, you can use sth like this

```
ajaxRunning = $.ajax(
   "?"+$('#yourForm').serialize(),
    {
       data: {
           anotherData: 'worksFine',
           etc: 'still works'
       },
       success: function(result) {
           doSth();
       },
       dataType: "json"
});
```

you can use in $.post and $.get as well

nJoy!

Answer (score 0):

Another library that solves this issue is [jquery.serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) by Mario Izquierdo. It works and extends jQuery.