# How do I convert a standard HTML form to JSON representation that includes all data?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple HTML form:

```
<form id="formid1" action="#" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr><td> First name: </td><td><input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname"/>  </td></tr>
        <tr><td>  Last name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>  </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Address:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Zip: </td><td> <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/> </td></tr>
        <tr><td> Sex:  </td><td> <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
            <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br /></td></tr>

        <tr><td>  </td><td>  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>

    </table>
</form>
```

I need to get a JSON representation of the Form elements including id, value, type, form action, form id etc.

I tried playing with the following code but I am not getting what I am looking for:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    var encoded = $.toJSON($('#formid1')); 

    $("#formid1").submit(function() {
  $.colorbox({html:'<p>Form Converted to JSON Data: <br /><br /><br /><br /><br /></p>'+ encoded  });
      return false;
    });

    });
</script>
```

I get:

```
{"length":1,"0":{"firstname":{},"lastname":{},"address":{},"zip":{},"sex":{"0":{},"1":{}},"6":{}},"context":{"jQuery16108216209608688556":1},"selector":"#formid1"}
```

close

Comment: In this example what would you like your JSON to look like?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert form data to JS object with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialize complex form to JSON object using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3672995/serialize-complex-form-to-json-object-using-jquery)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#formid1').serializeArray().reduce(function(obj, v) { obj[v.name] = v.value; return obj; }, { });
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm working on the same problem! The way I went around it was by using an onsubmit function rather than action. You pass everything within the form to a javascript function which then gives you access to the form data. The function I made uses an alert to show you have access to that data. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<body>

<form onsubmit="handleForm(this)">
<table>
    <tr><td> First name: </td><td><input type="text" name="firstname"  id="firstname"/>  </td></tr>
    <tr><td>  Last name: </td><td><input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/>  </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Address:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="address" id="address"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Zip: </td><td> <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip"/> </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Sex:  </td><td> <input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" /> Male<br />
        <input type="radio" name="sex" value="female" /> Female<br /></td></tr>

    <tr><td>  </td><td>  <input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>

</table>
</form>

<script>
function handleForm(arr) {
    alert(arr['firstname'].value + arr['lastname'].value);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP want's the form to be converted into JSON, not just getting a certain property from the form.